# How to connect a button made in UITableVC to show a separate view in Story Board

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on a small project with a few separate view controllers on my storyboard, and have have created a button the shows a `UITableViewController`, but I needed a way for the user to get back to the home page. I have created a button on top of the `MainTableVC`, and when I run the app, it shows the button. What I need is for the button to simply show my main view controller which is called just view controller. I am still learning so every step forward is a leap for me. Here is the code of the `viewDidLoad`, where I created the button.

```
let button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width / 2 - 25, y: self.view.frame.height - 70), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)))
button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(button1)
```

I also do have a `UITableViewController` listed in the class. Thank you everyone for your help, I appreciate it. So to summarize, I need to connect the `button1` I created to the viewcontroller, (because you can not just put a button on top of a tableview and then just control click to the other view and set "show". That actually makes it easier to say, I need to code the aspect of simply cntrl dragging from one button to a view and setting "show". Thanks so much everyone.

Comment: How is your UITableView being displayed? Are you pushing it onto the navigation stack with `self.navigationController.pushViewController` or presenting it modally with `self.presentViewController`?

Comment: I do have it setup to a navigation controller JoGoFo if thats what your asking.

Comment: JoGoFo it is self.presentViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much i understood.. you can manually create a button in your MainViewController using and add Target To it

```
let button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width / 2 - 25, y: self.view.frame.height - 70), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)))
button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainViewController.actionOpenTableView(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
 self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(button1)
```

Also create function actionOpenTableView in Your class capturing the
 Target of button 1 where you can push/present TableViewController(:here MyTableViewController) using segue or programmically.

```
func actionOpenTableView(btn:UIButton){
//if using segue of motherboard
 //    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MoveToTableView", sender: self) 


//if using programmically
let tableVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyTableVC")as! MyTableViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tableVC, animated: true)
}
```

if using pprogrammically make sure you provide StoryboardID to your TableviewController in Storyboard.

[image]
once you get on your TableViewController you can either use default back button.. or create custom method as follow for getting back to your MainViewController from MyTableViewController

```
@IBAction func mBackActionBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't add a button directly to your navigation controller. If you want to add a custom button, instead use the following:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Title", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(navButtonPressed))
```

You can then implement the method for the action:

```
func navButtonPressed() {
    // if pushed onto nav vc: 
    // _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    // if presented modally (as suggested in your comment:
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: and what should I put for #selector(navButtonPushed) ? thanks JoGoFo

Comment: `#selector` is a keyword, `navButtonPressed` is the name of the method you wish to be called when the user presses the button. This was the second part of my answer.

Comment: JoGoFo my code is not compiling here is a screenshot please check it out.              http://imgur.com/a/hQamM

Comment: You have nested your `navButtonPressed` func inside another function. Move it outside of that function (should be inside the class still).

Comment: JoGoFo now under the   'self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Title", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(navButtonPressed))' it has a compiling error of expected declaration. It is no longer in the viewdidload. Please help thanks man.